# Semi-Collapsed Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a sidebar that looks like: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbMIu.png)

This is the HTML code for it:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="new.php">➕ </a>
    <a class="active" href="#"></a>
    <a href="me.php">‍♂️</a>
    <a href="settings.php"></a>
    <a href="logout.php"></a>
    
    </div>
```

Now I want to add a button to make the bar bigger, and also display text using below code:

Using `onclick="openNav()"` I have found this way:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

If I hardcode in the text like this: `<a href="new.php">➕ New user</a>`, the text will also show when the bar is minimized, as in the first picture. But how can I only display the text if the bar is 250px?

This is my current sidebar CSS settings:

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
 
#sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
 
#sidebar a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: black !important;
}
 
#sidebar a:hover, #sidebar a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: black;
}

#sidebar a.active {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}
```

Comment: instead of changing **width and margin** can you use `translate`?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @RayeesAC Added now.

Comment: Please add `main` id element in html code.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, any questions I will be happy to answer :)

```js
function openNav() {
  // document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
  
  // OR YOU CAN
 
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
 
#sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#sidebar a span {
  display: none;
}
 
#sidebar a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: black !important;
}
 
#sidebar a:hover, #sidebar a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: black;
}

#sidebar a.active {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}


.open {
  width:250px !important;
}

.open  span {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

```html
 <div id="sidebar">
    <a href="new.php">➕<span> New user</span></a>
    <a class="active" href="#"><span> New user</span></a>
    <a href="me.php">‍♂️ <span> New user</span></a>
    <a href="settings.php"><span> New user</span></a>
    <a href="logout.php"><span> New user</span></a>
<button onclick="openNav()">Click</button>
   
    </div>
```

Comment: Very nice! I added my current full sidebar CSS code. Are you able to work with that also?

Comment: Check the new Edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

I changed some style of **#sidebar a**

```
#sidebar a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
```

> For align the text in single line by adding `white-space: nowrap;`

> overflow: hidden;  // For hide overflow content

> transition: all 600ms ease; // make animation smooth

```js
function openNav(btn) {
  btn.classList.toggle("active");
  if(btn.classList.contains("active")){
    btn.textContent = "x";
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }else{
    btn.textContent = "☰";
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "60px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "60px";
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  margin-left:60px;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
 
#sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 25px;
  word-spacing: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
 
#sidebar a:hover {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
   color: black !important;
}
 
#sidebar a:hover, #sidebar a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: black;
}

#sidebar a.active {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="new.php">➕ New User</a>
    <a class="active" href="#"> Home</a>
    <a href="me.php">‍♂️ Hello</a>
    <a href="settings.php"> Settings</a>
    <a href="logout.php"> Mobile</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav(this)">☰</button> 
</div>
```

**With My Demo :)**

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("big");
}
```

```css
#sidebar{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:50px;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
#sidebar a{
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
  padding:15px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-spacing: 10px;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
}
#sidebar a.active{background:#e6e6e6;}
#sidebar.big{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openNav()">SIDEBAR</button>
<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="new.php">➕ New User</a>
    <a class="active" href="#"> Home</a>
    <a href="me.php">‍♂️ Hello</a>
    <a href="settings.php"> Settings</a>
    <a href="logout.php"> Mobile</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I added just like :) Are you want like this